# What is best way to add data in Room on start?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to add some rows (about 180) on my database when application starts first time. I've found some tutorial with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` like https://android.jlelse.eu/pre-populate-room-database-6920f9acc870. But is there anouther ways to pre-popolute database?

AppDatabase.class

```
@Database(entities = {Country.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract CountryDao countryDao();

    public synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = buildDatabase(context);
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "countries").allowMainThreadQueries().addCallback(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onCreate(db);
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getInstance(context).countryDao().insertAll(Country.populateData());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: [here](https://github.com/sovoereign/RoomDataBaseExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/workholics/com/myroomdemo/DB), I used this example to populate database at opening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you are creating a new database, there is only one way to pre populate the database and that is registering [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback) callback and overriding `onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase db)` method.